# Can always roots be transformed into exponents?

Tags: proof-explanation, roots, exponentiation, radicals

The problem I find when assuming that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ it complies that $\sqrt[n]{x^m}=x^\frac{m}{n}$. But is it always true? Wouldn't this allow me to do this?: $x^\frac{m}{n}=x^{m\cdot \frac{1}{n}}=x^{\frac{1}{n}\cdot m}=(x^\frac{1}{n})^m=(\sqrt[n]{x})^m$. But this shouldn't be always true when working with real numbers, since if $x\in \mathbb{R}$ this would mean that $\sqrt{(x)^3}=(\sqrt{x})^3$, but since $\sqrt{x^3}=\sqrt{x^2 x}=\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x}=|x|\sqrt{x}$, and $(\sqrt{x})^3=\sqrt{x}\cdot \sqrt{x} \cdot \sqrt{x}=x\sqrt{x}$, but not always $|x|=x$... does any one has some notes or book chapters where all the roots and powers properties and theorems are proven? Not even for complex numbers some of these properties hold.

Comment: Not sure if I have seen a similar question before. Anyway, the flaw in your reasoning is the step $x^{\frac{1}{n}\cdot m}=(x^{\frac{1}{n}})^m$. This step holds only if $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is defined.

Comment: Do you know any book or notes where all these requisites and theorems are proven and explained? I hope that EVERY properties about root and powers.

Comment: I once saw $-1={(-1)}^{1/1}={(-1)}^{2/2}=\{{(-1)}^2\}^{\frac 1 2}=1$

Comment: I would say: $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is $x^{1/n}$ by definition.  But the "rule" $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$ is not an actual "rule" without some assumptions.  The easiest assumptions under which is is true are (a) $x>0, a,b\in \mathbb R$,  or (b) $x \ne 0, a,b \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: The problem is in your very first sentence. You are assuming that it is true for all real $x$ when it is actually only true for all nonnegative $x$.

Comment: @saulspatz  I wrote "$x>0$" in my comment because of problems with things like $0^{-1}$.

Comment: @GEdgar I guess I was assuming $m,n$ are positive integers.